# Can constructor in Java inherited classes be empty

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, static-methods, instance-methods

I've got 2 classes (`Date` and `Student`) in the same project. I need to test the `Student` class but am unable to call an instance method in a static method. I tried to create a reference to the instance by adding a `Student a = new Student()` under `public static void main(String[]args)`, but this needs a `public Student()` constructor to be created. However, this results in the following error:

> Implicit super constructor Date() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

I am able to solve the problem if I changed the instance method to a static one. But was wondering if there is any other way I can call the instance method in the main method?

`Date` class:

```
public class Date {

int day;
int month;
int year;

public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.day=day;
    this.month=month;
    this.year=year;
}

public boolean equals(Date d) {
    if(d.day==this.day&&d.month==this.month&&d.year==this.year)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean after(Date d1, Date d2) {
    if(d1.day>d2.day&&d1.month>d2.month&&d1.year>d2.year)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

`Student` class:

```
public class Student extends Date{

public String name;
public boolean gender;

public Student(String name, boolean gender, int day, int month, int year) {
    super(day, month, year);
    this.name=name;
    this.gender=gender;
}

public Student() {

}

public boolean equals(Student s) {
    Date d=new Date(s.day,s.month,s.year);
    if(s.name==this.name&&s.gender==this.gender&&equals(d)==true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean oldGender(Student[]stds) {
    Student old=stds[0];
    Date oldDate = new Date(old.day,old.month,old.year);
    for(int i=0;i<stds.length;i++)
    {
        Date d = new Date(stds[i].day,stds[i].month,stds[i].year);
        if(after(oldDate,d)==false)
        {
            old=stds[i];
        }
    }
    return old.gender;
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    Student s1=new Student("Jemima",true,2,3,1994);
    Student s2=new Student("Theo",false,30,5,1994);
    Student s3=new Student("Joanna",true,2,8,1995);
    Student s4=new Student("Jonmo",false,24,8,1995);
    Student s5=new Student("Qianhui",true,25,12,1994);
    Student s6=new Student("Asaph",false,2,1,1995);
    Student[]stds= {s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6};
    Student a = new Student();
    System.out.println(oldGender(stds));
}

}
```

Comment: It is crazy that a Student will inherit from a Date **but** anyway, why did you initially try to do `Student a = new Student()`?

Comment: BTW, the compiler is telling you the answer to your question -no

Comment: @ScaryWombat Isn't `Student a = new Student()` followed by `a.oldGender` the only way to create a reference to the instance in a static method?

Comment: No, change your method to be `public static boolean oldGender(Student[]stds) `

Comment: I knew student where all numbers but now there are also dates ! You probably don't want to extends `Date` but add a `Date` variable in `Student` class. Or this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AxelH Is it possible to call the methods and constructor in the `Date` class in the `Student` class without using inheritance?

Comment: You can `Date date = new Date(x,y,z)` then use the methods with the instance `date`.. `Date.after` is `static` so you don't even need an instance. You have some issues with the understanding of OOP for the moment, this can't be answered here unfortunately because this would become a book..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are extending some class, you are obligated to call 1 of the constructors of that class using `super(args)` construct. Constructor of newly created class can be whatever you like.

When extended class have no args constructor, then constructor definition can be ommited in extending class. This may sound like an exception, but in fact it is not. Compiler adds empty constructor on the fly for you.

When you explicitly define empty constructor on the other hand (like you did) you are obligated to call super-class constructor in it.

That is exactly what error says.

```
public Student() { 
//Here you need to call super(int day, int month, int year); as   Date(int day, int month, int year) 
}
```

or delcare no args constructor in `Date` class

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having an XY problem. You ultimately want to call `oldGender` but can't because `oldGender` is non-static, so you tries to create a `Student` instance, but fails because it does not have a constructor.

From what I can see, `oldGender` does not really need any data from `this`, so it could just be written as a `static` method, just like you did with `Date.after`. Just make it static! And you will be able to call it like

```
Student.oldGender(...)
```

Note that `Student` extending `Date` makes no sense to me. A student is not a kind of date. I think you should rethink that.

I made added a `Date` field in `Student` called `d`. I think this is probably what you were trying to do but didn't:

```
class Date {

    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

    public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        this.day=day;
        this.month=month;
        this.year=year;
    }

    public boolean equals(Date d) {
        return d.day == this.day && d.month == this.month && d.year == this.year;
    }

    public static boolean after(Date d1, Date d2) {
        return d1.day > d2.day && d1.month > d2.month && d1.year > d2.year;
    }

}

class Student{

    Date d;
    String name;
    boolean gender;

    public Student(String name, boolean gender, int day, int month, int year) {
        this.d = new Date(day, month, year);
        this.name=name;
        this.gender=gender;
    }

    public boolean equals(Student s) {
        return s.name == this.name && s.gender == this.gender && this.d.equals(s.d);
    }

    public static boolean oldGender(Student[]stds) {
        Student old=stds[0];
        for (Student std : stds) {
            if (!after(old.d, std.d)) {
                old = std;
            }
        }
        return old.gender;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Student s1=new Student("Jemima",true,2,3,1994);
        Student s2=new Student("Theo",false,30,5,1994);
        Student s3=new Student("Joanna",true,2,8,1995);
        Student s4=new Student("Jonmo",false,24,8,1995);
        Student s5=new Student("Qianhui",true,25,12,1994);
        Student s6=new Student("Asaph",false,2,1,1995);
        Student[]stds= {s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6};
        System.out.println(oldGender(stds));
    }

}
```

Comment: My date field has to be under the date class no choice. Trying now to figure a way out to call that field in this class without using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Date() constructor is concerned, I think you need to add no-arg Constructor in Date class as it will be called implicitly when calling no-arg or default Student constructor.

In case of calling the 'oldGender(Student[]stds)' method there might be no other way than making it 'static' to be called in the main() method.

Answer (score -1):

```
Implicit super constructor Date() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor
```

In your Date Class, the no-argument constructor is not written explicitly.

> The No-argument (or) default constructor will be generated if there is no other constructor is present in a class